# unclear with this tower of hanoi recursive call

Tags: c, algorithm, function, recursion

```
void TOH(int n,char x,char y,char z);
void main()
{
  int n;
  printf("nEnter number of plates:");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  TOH(n,'A','B','C');
  getch();
}

void TOH(int n,char x,char y,char z)
{
  if(n>0)
  {
    TOH(n-1,x,z,y);
    printf("n%c -> %c",x,y);
    TOH(n-1,z,y,x);
  }
}
```

In this coding i'm so confused with recursive call and how the characters and 
    integers  are handled in function call,can anyone explain with a simple demonstration.

Comment: Rename you vars to something better and try to figure it out: n = number_of_plates, x = first_tower, y = second_tower, z = third_tower.

Comment: also - shouldn't the call in main be `TOH(n,'A','B','C');`?

Comment: @ItayKaro edited ! thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally - to solve the tower of hanoi problem with n plates you should:

1. Move n-1 plates from A to C
2. Move the single plate on A to B
3. Move the n-1 plates from C to B

#1 is the same problem with n-1 instead of n plates when the towers are ordered A, C, B
#3 is the same problem with n-1 instead of n plates when the towers are ordered A, B, A

For example:
for `n = 3`
 1. Move 2 plate from A to C
 2. Move the single plate on A to B
 3. Move the 2 plates from C to B

#1 is mapped to the call `TOH(n-1,x,z,y);`
#2 is mapped to the call `printf("n%c -> %c",x,y);`
#3 is mapped to the call `TOH(n-1,z,y,x);`

**EDIT - example**
So this will be the order of the calls (indentation is a recursive call)

- TOH(3, 'A', 'B', 'C') // move 3 plates from A to B

  - TOH(2, 'A', 'C', 'B')  // move 2 plates from A to C

    - TOH(1, 'A', 'B', 'C') // move one plate from A to B
    - move one plate from A to C
    - TOH(1, 'B', 'C', 'A') // move one plate from B to C
    - // Now we have 1 plate in A and 2 plates in C
  - move one plate from A to B
  - TOH(2, 'C', 'B', 'A') // move 2 plates from C to B

    - TOH(1, 'C', 'A', 'B') // move one plate from C to A
    - move one plate from C to B
    - TOH(1, 'A', 'B', 'C') // move the last plate from A to B
    - DONE - ALL PLATES ARE IN PLACE

Comment: @italy karo practically i know how they work but couldn't get how the values are passed in this function call

Comment: for eg. n=3 TOH(2,x,z,y) is passed in this case two recursive calls are made.this part is the confusion for me.can yu elaborate this one in between thnx for yur eg

Comment: added an example - hope it helps

Comment: helped me a lot thnx!